# Where to start for WSN development

Tags: wireless, tinyos, sensor-fusion

I want to get my hands on WSN development. So far I have been working with TinyOS and TOSSIM and I have some familiarity with the basic concepts involved in WSN field. However, I want to slowly move to practice and actually start working with physical motes. Where can I find practical starter/dev kits/motes that I can get my hands on? **Micaz**, **Mica-II** and **sun SPOT** are some of the options. Do you guys know any other?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded a series of tutorials on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnGjYOy4we8aCBSvZJorXajIDYbSsUmtX) and also my [Website](http://www.eetutorials.com) that might be helpful for you to get started.